# Difficulty composing log messages for the RIO.Logger via UTF8Builder

Tags: haskell, logging, rio

I'm using the RIO monad and RIO libraries and want to add logging. The RIO log functions, like `logInfo`, take a `Utf8Builder` as parameter, which is a wrapper around a `ByteString` builder. I would like to efficiently insert log statements in my code. However, I am not sure how to transform simple `Text`, `String` and `ByteString` values into the appropriate Builder.

This does not type-check:

```
logInfo $ "Identifier: " <> UUID.toByteString myId
```

where `myId` is a `UUID` value. The type checker error is

```
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Utf8Builder’
                  with actual type ‘bytestring-0.10.10.0:Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString’
```

I tried converting the UUID into `Text` instead, tried to use `encodeUtf8Builder` and then wrap the resulting `Builder` in an `Utf8Builder`, but to no avail.

My gut feeling says that logging should simply work, without lots of conversions; so I am probably missing the obvious route. How can I simply log values using the RIO logger?

Comment: How about this?  https://hackage.haskell.org/package/rio-0.1.15.1/docs/RIO.html#v:displayBytesUtf8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a `Display` instance for your `UUID`, which will allow you combine with `Utf8Builder` efficiently and easily use it in your logs.

```hs
instance Display UUID.UUID where
  display = displayBytesUtf8 . UUID.toASCIIBytes
```

The only reason why `displayBytesUtf8` can be used is because you know the content is in ascii. In other words it is your responsibility when creating `Display` instance that it produces correctly encoded utf8 bytes.

After that you can use it in your logs like so:

```hs
logInfo $ "Identifier: " <> display myId
```

Creating `Display` instance isn't strictly speaking necessary, you can just use a helper function if you don't want to create orphan instances or wrapper newtypes. This will do just fine:

```hs
displayUUID :: UUID.UUID -> Utf8Builder
displayUUID = displayBytesUtf8 . UUID.toASCIIBytes
```

Reason why I mention `Display` is because it is idiomatic approach in RIO for logging with custom types.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Unfortunately, there is surprisingly little information on this detail in the documentation.